# Wordpress include plugin in post page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Hi I am trying to use the advanced layer slider in my wordpress post page. However my code pasted in the header.php file works only on the pages, not posts, I can see the shortcode showing up though in the top of the posts page. Is there anyway to include the code needed from the plugin easily?

Thanks in advanced,

James

Sorry about the formatting

Single.php

```
<?php
global $avia_config;

/*
 * get_header is a basic wordpress function, used to retrieve the header.php file in your theme directory.
 */
 get_header();

$title  = __('Blog - Latest News', 'avia_framework'); //default blog title
$t_link = home_url('/');
$t_sub = "";

if(avia_get_option('frontpage') && $new = avia_get_option('blogpage'))
{
    $title  = get_the_title($new); //if the blog is attached to a page use this title
    $t_link = get_permalink($new);
    $t_sub =  avia_post_meta($new, 'subtitle');
}

if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'header', true) != 'no') echo avia_title(array('heading'=>'strong', 'title' => $title, 'link' => $t_link, 'subtitle' => $t_sub));
```

?>
        '>

```
        <div class='container template-blog template-single-blog '>

            <main class='content units <?php avia_layout_class( 'content' ); ?>' <?php avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'content','post_type'=>'post'));?>>

                <?php
                /* Run the loop to output the posts.
                * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
                *
                */

                    get_template_part( 'includes/loop', 'index' );

                    //show related posts based on tags if there are any
                    get_template_part( 'includes/related-posts');

                    //wordpress function that loads the comments template "comments.php"
                    comments_template( '/includes/comments.php');

                ?>

            <!--end content-->
            </main>

            <?php
            $avia_config['currently_viewing'] = "blog";
            //get the sidebar
            get_sidebar();


            ?>


        </div><!--end container-->

    </div><!-- close default .container_wrap element -->
```

Page.php

```
<?php
```

global $avia_config;

```
/*
 * get_header is a basic wordpress function, used to retrieve the header.php file in your theme directory.
 */
 get_header();


 if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'header', true) != 'no') echo avia_title();
 ?>

    <div class='container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color <?php avia_layout_class( 'main' ); ?>'>

        <div class='container'>

            <main class='template-page content  <?php avia_layout_class( 'content' ); ?> units' <?php avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'content','post_type'=>'page'));?>>

                <?php
                /* Run the loop to output the posts.
                * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
                */

                $avia_config['size'] = avia_layout_class( 'main' , false) == 'entry_without_sidebar' ? '' : 'entry_with_sidebar';
                get_template_part( 'includes/loop', 'page' );
                ?>

            <!--end content-->
            </main>

            <?php

            //get the sidebar
            $avia_config['currently_viewing'] = 'page';
            get_sidebar();

            ?>

        </div><!--end container-->

    </div><!-- close default .container_wrap element -->
```

Header.php

```
<?php
global $avia_config;

$style      = $avia_config['box_class'];
$responsive = avia_get_option('responsive_layout','responsive');
$blank      = isset($avia_config['template']) ? $avia_config['template'] : "";
$headerS    = !$blank ? avia_header_setting() : "";
$headerMenu = $responsive ? avia_get_option('header_menu','mobile_drop_down') : "";
```

?>

 class=" ">

" />

RSS2 Feed" href="" />
" />

';

?>


     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to  such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */

    wp_head();
?>

'body')); ?>>

```
<div id='wrap_all'>

    <?php if(!$blank){ ?>

    <header id='header' class=' header_color <?php avia_is_dark_bg('header_color'); echo " ".$headerMenu; ?>' <?php avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'header','post_type'=>'forum'));?>>

        <?php

        if($responsive && $headerMenu == 'mobile_slide_out')
        {
            echo '<a id="advanced_menu_toggle" href="#" '.av_icon_string('mobile_menu').'></a>';
            echo '<a id="advanced_menu_hide" href="#"   '.av_icon_string('close').'></a>';
        }


        $social_args = array('outside'=>'ul', 'inside'=>'li', 'append' => '');

        //subheader, only display when the user chooses a social header
        if(strpos($headerS,'social_header') !== false)
        {
        ?>
        <div id='header_meta' class='container_wrap container_wrap_meta'>

              <div class='container'>
              <?php
                    /*
                    *   display the themes social media icons, defined in the wordpress backend
                    *   the avia_social_media_icons function is located in includes/helper-social-media-php
                    */

                    if(strpos($headerS,'bottom_nav_header') === false) avia_social_media_icons($social_args);

                    //display the small submenu
                    echo "<nav class='sub_menu' ".avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'nav', 'echo' => false)).">";
                        $avia_theme_location = 'avia2';
                        $avia_menu_class = $avia_theme_location . '-menu';
                        $args = array(
                            'theme_location'=>$avia_theme_location,
                            'menu_id' =>$avia_menu_class,
                            'container_class' =>$avia_menu_class,
                            'fallback_cb' => '',
                            'container'=>'',
                            'echo' =>false
                        );

                        $nav  = wp_nav_menu($args);
                        echo $nav;

                        $phone = avia_get_option('phone');
                        $phone_class = !empty($nav) ? "with_nav" : "";
                        if($phone) echo "<div class='phone-info {$phone_class}'><span>{$phone}</span></div>";


                        /*
                        * Hook that can be used for plugins and theme extensions (currently: the wpml language selector)
                        */
                        do_action('avia_meta_header');
                    echo '</nav>';
                ?>
              </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>



        <div  id='header_main' class='container_wrap container_wrap_logo'>

                <?php
                /*
                * Hook that can be used for plugins and theme extensions (currently:  the woocommerce shopping cart)
                */
                do_action('ava_main_header');

                ?>

                <div class='container'>

                    <?php
                    /*
                    *   display the theme logo by checking if the default logo was overwritten in the backend.
                    *   the function is located at framework/php/function-set-avia-frontend-functions.php in case you need to edit the output
                    */
                    echo avia_logo(AVIA_BASE_URL.'images/layout/logo.png', false, 'strong');


                        if(strpos($headerS,'social_header') !== false && strpos($headerS,'bottom_nav_header') !== false) avia_social_media_icons($social_args);

                    /*
                    *   display the main navigation menu
                    *   modify the output in your wordpress admin backend at appearance->menus
                    */
                        $extraOpen = $extraClose = "";
                        if(strpos($headerS,'bottom_nav_header') !== false){ $extraClose = "</div></div><div id='header_main_alternate' class='container_wrap'><div class='container'>";  }

                        echo $extraClose;

                        echo "<nav class='main_menu' data-selectname='".__('Select a page','avia_framework')."' ".avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'nav', 'echo' => false)).">";
                            $avia_theme_location = 'avia';
                            $avia_menu_class = $avia_theme_location . '-menu';
                            $args = array(
                                'theme_location'    => $avia_theme_location,
                                'menu_id'           => $avia_menu_class,
                                'container_class'   => $avia_menu_class,
                                'fallback_cb'       => 'avia_fallback_menu',
                                'walker'            => new avia_responsive_mega_menu()
                            );

                            wp_nav_menu($args);
                        echo '</nav>';

                        /*
                        * Hook that can be used for plugins and theme extensions
                        */
                        do_action('ava_after_main_menu');
                    ?>
                <!-- end container-->
                </div>



        <!-- end container_wrap-->
        </div>

        <div class='header_bg'></div>

    <!-- end header -->
    </header>

<?php } //end blank check ?>
<div id='main'>
```

Comment: Please share your header.php, page.php and single.php codes here.